# Was that city in Wakanda?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron, black-panther

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, after events on the boat in a salvage yard on the "African Coast",

> the Hulk goes on a rampage

in a nearby city. I've seen people state that this city is a Wakandan city, but I don't recall seeing any indicator that this is true.

Is this unnamed city in Wakanda?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**I don’t think so.**

The filming location is Johannesburg.  Desmond Mthembu is the head of the film commission in the local Gauteng province, and told a [local newspaper](http://www.sabreakingnews.co.za/2014/02/10/avengers-sequel-film-shoot-starts-in-jozi-tomorrow/):

> “**The great thing about this movie is that they are shooting Johannesburg as Johannesburg.** Often you will find filmmakers will shoot in Johannesburg and portray the location as Los Angeles. This time around the first 10 minutes of the film will be of Johannesburg.”

I don’t know if we actually see that on-screen, but I see no reason why he’d be told that by Marvel if it wasn’t actually the case.

A few additional considerations:

- In the comics, Wakanda is concealed from the outside world. In Iron Man’s helmet, when he’s searching for news, he sees tweets and footage from CNN. And later Maria says, “The news is loving you guys”. Not in keeping with the whole secrecy element.
- We know that Ulysses Klaw has stolen significant amounts of Vibranium from the Wakandans, and been branded a thief accordingly. If this city was Wakandan, he’d be right on their doorstep. I think it unlikely he’d stay there for long, if he could.
- Adding weight to the idea that this is Johannesburg in-universe, a cursory [image search for “Johannesburg police”](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=johannesburg+police&iax=1&ia=images) shows up people dressed in identical uniform to those in the film.

Comment: I believe that in the scene where the Avengers identify Klaw (and the brand on him), someone specifies that he escaped from Wakanda with the vibranium he stole. This seems to indicate that he is no longer in Wakanda prior to the battle taking place.

Comment: Isn't the location introduced as a "Ship Graveyard". It would be difficult to be Johannesburg since Joburg is landlocked.